# The correct preposition after "I'm dying"

Tags: prepositions, phrases, informal-language

Saying "I'm dying" alone is normal and correct, but what if it was followed (for any reason) by a preposition? Would "at" be the correct one to use as in (I'm dying **at** this)?

- It was stated in that specific format by someone as a sub-comment to a funny remark, but I'm not sure of their nationality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In formal, correct grammar, "at" would not be correct. A grammatically correct version might be "I'm dying **because of** this" or "I'm dying **from** this," but either one would sound strange in the context you have described. Grammatical or not, "I'm dying at [something funny]" has become a common idiom, especially on the internet, and it is not readily replaced by a truly grammatical alternative.

If you want to express the same sentiment but are determined to be grammatically correct, you could say "I'm going to die laughing at this!" or "That's so funny I'm going to die!" It's easy to get wrong, though, and just slightly misusing any idiom involving death could make people uncomfortable.

Comment: You have hit the nails [ha ha] on the head.

Comment: I agree with this. Maybe "at" has become commonly used in this context esp. on the internet because it can be written succinctly with the symbol '@'.

Comment: When speaking, I'd reply to someone who said something  funny with "You're killing me!" Same origin, "dying from laughter".